# Search for an exact phrase with InstaSearch for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

How can I search for an exact phrase in Eclipse instasearch?

When I search for

one two

it will find also files that contain only one. And the file containing the exact phrase is not at the top of the result list.

**UPDATE:**

@Ad Infinitum suggested to turn off the option:

```
Find similar matches when no exact matches found
```

but strangely it does not work as you can see from the screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instasearch is already looking for the exact match. However, if it cannot find an exact match, it looks for the alternatives. If you only want to display the exact match, there is an option, which you can unmark the fuzzy search, in the instasearch's preferences.

In order to get the instasearch's preferences.

**Window -> Preferences**

when the Eclipse's preferences dialog is openned, you can write instasearch in the search text field, which brings you the instasearch preferences.

[image]

I hope that is the option, you are looking for.

**EDIT**
When this option is unmarked, the results will be something like that if there is no match. 0 matches and under of it, there is more selection, which shows the fuzzy search results.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it sound like an option I was looking for! Unfortunately it does not turn off similar matches. I updated my question with a screenshot demonstrating it does not work for me.

Comment: @mmm I am sorry that it does not work you. I have editted my answer, which shows the results if I want to display only the exact matches.